# Strip "underscore" and other namespaces from XML tags and convert it into camelCase string

Tags: string, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have a xml like below in byte array

```
<branch_type>
   <branch_name></branch_name>
</branch_type>...
```

which i need to convert into

```
<branchType>
   <branchName></branchName>
<branchType>...
```

Any suggestions?

I am trying to unmarshal the xml above into java object using JAXB.
But since the xml tag names having underscore, it is not getting applied into java properties.

So I thought of going with String manipulation before unmarshall the content. Is there any better way to do it?

Java file extends XSDClass has getBranchName and getBranchType etc. It is not JAXB generated objects and not having any annotations.
I would like to unmarshal the xml without modifying java classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the xml structure you can use an XSLTransformation.

***Template***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="branch_type">
      <branchType>
        <branchName><xsl:value-of select="branch_name"/></branchName>
      </branchType>
      </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

***Input***

```
<branch_type>
   <branch_name>aaaa</branch_name>
</branch_type>
```

---

***Output***

```
<branchType>
   <branchName>aaaa</branchName>
</branchType>
```